# i am trying to create multiple tables in a database

Tags: python, sqlite

```
error:  cursor.execute(
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Order": syntax error
```

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("Cookie.DB")
print("The Employee database is created!")

cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer(
        customerID TXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        customerFirstName TEXT NOT NULL,
        customerLastName TXT NOT NULL,
        address TXT NOT NULL,
        email TXT NOT NULL,
        Phone TXT NOT NULL,
        creditCardInfo TXT NOT NULL
        
    )
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Order(
        orderID TXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (customerID)
        REFERENCES Customer (customerID),
        customerName TXT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (cartID)
        REFERENCES ShoppingCart (cartID),
        orderPrice float NOT NULL,
        dateCreated date NOT NULL,
        dateShipped date NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cookies(
        CookieID TXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        cookieName TXT NOT NULL,
        unitCost float NOT NULL,
        soldOutOrNot bool NOT NULL
       
    )
 
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ShoppingCart(
        CartID TXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (customerID)
        REFERENCES Customer (customerID),
        FOREIGN KEY (cookieID)
        REFERENCES Cookies (cookieID),
        quantity INT NOT NULL,
        dateAdded date NOT NULL,
        soldOutOrNot bool NOT NULL
        )

    """
)
conn.commit()
print("The employee table is created!")
```

Comment: I suggest you to use Django

Comment: `Order` is a reserved word in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I see the syntax you are using is wrong as far as I am able to understand try running individual queries like

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

# run for each table...
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums
                  (title text, artist text, release_date text, 
                   publisher text, media_type text)""")
```

Comment: So you have to add each table individually. They can not be nested inside cursor.execute()